# perl использование NYTProf

Tags: perl, active-perl

в логе nytprof.out результат сжатый, об этом свидетельствует запись:
**Compressed at level 6 with zlib 1.2.8**
как отключить сжатие в NYTProf?

Comment: [https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf#compress=...](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf#compress=...)

Comment: спасибо, но я это видел перед тем как запостить вопрос. Первое предложение "Задайте уровень сжатия"... Спасибо кеп, вопрос как это сделать? Есть какой-то конфиг файл или это параметр?

Comment: Написано установить параметр среды NYTPROF, установил, ничего не поменялось (у меня винда)

Comment: нужно было cygwin перезапустить )

Comment: А какая разница, собственно? `nytprof.out` - это внутренняя кухня, зачем нужно в неё влезать не очень понятно. Разве что места на дискете не хватает :)